# Grammar for $\{ (n_a(w) - n_b(w)) mod\ 3 = 2 \} $

Tags: finite-automata

What is the grammar for $$\{ (n_a(w) - n_b(w)) mod\ 3 = 2 \} $$

please guide me with this. I tried to draw DFA to find grammar but I can't.

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from the initial state $q_0$: the current value of $(n_a(w) - n_b(w)) \pmod 3$ is 0. Next, if you read $a$ in $q_0$, then the current value of $(n_a(w) - n_b(w)) \pmod 3$, which is 0, becomes 1, so go to $q_1$, while if you read $b$, the value of $(n_a(w) - n_b(w)) \pmod 3$ becomes 2, and so go to $q_2$ (which will be a final state). Then you can do the same for $q_1$ and $q_2$: in $q_1$, if you read $a$, then the current value of $(n_a(w) - n_b(w)) \pmod 3$, which is 1, becomes 2, so go to $q_2$, and so on...

In conclusion: when you read $a$ the value of $(n_a(w) - n_b(w)) \pmod 3$ is incremented by 1 (modulo 3, of course), while if you read $b$ it is decremented by 1, and in state $q_i$ the current value of $(n_a(w) - n_b(w)) \pmod 3$ is $i$.